# Mostrar video de fondo en un div en Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, video

No se por qué no me aperece ningun video al poner este código:

```js
import React from 'react';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import './Carousel.css'

export default function Carousel() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <div class='vidContain'>
                <div class='vid'>
                    <video loop autoPlay>
                        <source src="videocarousel.mp4" type="video/mp4" ></source>
                    </video>
                </div>
                <div class='content'>Team Manager es juego en equipo</div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```css
.vidContain {
    height: 600px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
}
.vid {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; left:0;
    height: 90vh;
    z-index: -1;
}    
.content {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    background: black;
    color:white;
}
```

El caso es que si sustituyo la etiqueta `<video>` por el paquete `React Player`:

```
<ReactPlayer url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysz5S6PUM-U' playing />
```

sí funciona. Por lo que me lleva a pensar que el bug está en la etiqueta `<video>`

El problema es que `ReactPlayer` no me sirve porque me aparecen los controles de `Youtube`, aparte de otras desventajas. Me gustaría hacerlo con la etiqueta video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tienes todo bien implementado, el vídeo te debe funcionar de la misma forma que funciona sin hacer uso de `React`. Si no te funciona, el problema debe estar en otro lado. Aquí te dejo un snippet funcional con un vídeo público para que veas que funciona. Algunas cosas que debes tener en cuenta:

- En `JavaScript` (y por lo tanto en `JSX`), no uses `class`, esta es una [palabra reservada](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Palabras_Reservadas), así que en su lugar en `React` es necesario usar `className`
- No me queda claro por tu código, por qué estás aplicando `z-index` con valor `-1` al contenedor del vídeo. Dependiendo de tu layout o los elementos que tengas posicionados, puedes estar ocultándolo.
- Estás intentando reproducir el vídeo automáticamente con `autoPlay`, aunque esto no es recomendado, si no quieres que navegadores como Chrome bloqueen la reproducción, [añade la propiedad `muted` al vídeo](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#new-behaviors).

```js
function Carousel() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>      
      <div className='vid'>
        <video loop autoPlay muted>
          <source src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/flower.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Carousel/>, document.getElementById('videoApp'));
```

```css
.vid {
    height: 90vh;
}  
.vid video {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="videoApp"></div>
```